# Silverlight EventHandler DependencyProperty binding

Tags: silverlight, xaml, binding, event-handling, dependency-properties

I have a UserControl that I am trying to hook up event handlers from a parent control to.  I want to do as little in code as I can and am running into some problems.  Here is my setup:

in NewUserControl code behind I have:

```
 public RoutedEventHandler PrintClickHandler { get; set; }
 public DependencyProperty PrintClickHandlerProperty = 
     DependencyProperty.Register("PrintClickHandler", typeof(RoutedEventHandler), 
                                 typeof(NewUserControl), new PropertyMetadata(null));
```

In MyParentControl I have:

```
 public RoutedEventHandler PrintClickHandler
 {
    get { return btnPrintCall_Click; }
 }
 private void btnPrintCall_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {
    // some code
 }
```

And finally in the MyParentControls xaml I have the binding for NewUserControl.PrintClickHandler:

```
<NewUserControl PrintClickHandler="{Binding Path=PrintClickHandler, 
    RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=local:MyParentControl, AncestorLevel=1}}" />
```

Now in the debugger I can implement all the getters and setters the classic way to hit breakpoints when they are called.  I see the getter for MyParentControl.PrintClickHandler in the being hit, but the setter for NewUserControl.PrintClickHandler is never hit.  I also have no errors or warnings related to this binding in the output.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This question is erroneous.  As I am dealing with an event, using a dependency property is inappropriate.  I can simple add a public Event property in my code behind which can be set in the xaml to an appropriate event handler method.

Answer (score 1):

I've never tried doing events like this, but it does look like your dependency property may by setup incorrectly, try:

```
public RoutedEventHandler PrintClickHandler
{
    get { return (RoutedEventHandler)GetValue(PrintClickHandlerProperty); }
    set { SetValue(PrintClickHandlerProperty, value); }
}

public static DependencyProperty PrintClickHandlerProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
    "PrintClickHandler", 
    typeof(RoutedEventHandler), 
    typeof(NewUserControl), 
    new PropertyMetadata(null));
```

Comment: The setter never gets called.

Comment: The setter of the property will not get called when setting via xaml, only when set via code. I also noticed that the DependencyProperty was not static. I modified my answer to include how your DP should look. For future use, you can use the 'propdp' shortcut within Visual Studio to create proper DP. Just type propdp and hit tab.